# implementing jquery.tools 1.1.2 and jquery-1.4.2.min.js in grails 3.2.8

Tags: javascript, grails

I am trying to implement  jquery.tools 1.1.2 and jquery-1.4.2.min.js  in grails 3.2.8

Attached the cod which I was trying. Its not using the jquery at all in grails 3.2.8. Please suggest

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
<asset:javascript src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></asset:javascript>
<asset:javascript src="jquery-ui.js"></asset:javascript>
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
$("#tabs").css("display","block");
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Tab 1 Content</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>Tab - 2 Content</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<p>Tab - 3 Content</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks
Pooja

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is jquery.tools a separate dependency to standard jquery and jquery-ui?

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove `</asset:javascript>` and use like this

```
<asset:javascript src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
<asset:javascript src="jquery-ui.js">
```

Place your javacsript files to this directory

```
your_project\grails-app\assets\javascripts\
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am gettig 'Grails tag [asset:javascript] was not closed' error. The tags has to be closed rt?

Comment: Is it your index.gsp or other GSP page?

Comment: its the index.gsp

Comment: Include `<meta name="layout" content="main"/>` before that lines.

Comment: I tried both index.gsp and test.gsp.  But it failed

Comment: The tab bar is the only one which is not working... Button and other features are working fine... Please let me know the proper way to implement the tab bar in grails 3.2.8

Comment: You should remove these lines
`<asset:javascript src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></asset:javascript>
<asset:javascript src="jquery-ui.js"></asset:javascript>`
Grails uses bootstrap UI so you shouldn't use jQuery UI.